# How to customize Syncfusion WP8 SfColorPalette control?

Tags: windows-phone-8, syncfusion

I need to customize some features in the control, but I did not saw any public property/method for:

1. Hide the control header;
2. Change the control header (like "Select your favorite color" instead of "Colors");
3. Hide the button for change Swatches
4. Set default Swatch for the palette.

Tnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion for Query #2

XAML:

```
<sync:SfColorPalette FontSize="20"/>
```

Create a resource file with the given details. They are mandatory.

File name       : Syncfusion.SfColorPickers.WinRT.Resources

File extension  : .resw

Resources       : Colors, Swatches

Add the resource file to your project. The header will change automatically.